# List menu, round corners at top and bottom, hidden entrys, square on hover

Tags: css, html, sass

I have a responsive list-menu

```html
<ul class="js-dropdown active" style="display: block;">

<!-- custom menu -->

                        <li class="mobile-only"><a href="/static/Bikemap_Job_Webdesign.pdf"><b>We are hiring!</b></a></li>
                        <li class="mobile-only"><a href="/pages/apps">Apps</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/en/events/">Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/en/traininglog/">Training log</a></li>
                        <li class="mobile-only"><a href="/de/pages/allgemeine-fragen/">General questions</a></li>
                        <li class="mobile-only"><a href="/de/pages/fragen-zur-technik/">Questions about technology</a></li>
                        <li class="mobile-only"><a href="/de/pages/werbung-auf-bikemap/">Advertise on Bikemap</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/shirts/"><b>NEW: T-Shirt Shop</b></a></li>

</ul>
```

```css
    li {
        .mobile-only{
             display:none;
        }
        display: block;

        &:first-child:before {
            color: $dropdown-bg;
            content: "\f0d8";
            font-family: 'FontAwesome';
            position: absolute;
            right: 8px;
            top: -8px;
        }

        &:first-child a {
            border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
        }

        &:last-child a {
            border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
        }

    }
```

On a Desktop you only see the plain li-elements and the Top and the Bottom of the menu has round corners. But on hover it loses the round Corner (or forget that it is the first-child) and is a squarefield -> First element fE.

please Help,

tom

Comment: You might want to close your list items by adding `</li>`?

Comment: Thats just copyed out from the Inspector, the HTML is valid all look like <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>

Comment: Then please share your valid code...

Comment: Unless your problem is with Sass, only provide the compiled CSS.